# Optimal way to find similar value from a large table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where i am storing more than 1000000 names in mysql. Now the task of my application is a bit typical. I not only searches for names in the database,but also finds similar names. Suppose the name is entered as `christian`, then the application will show suggested names like `christine`, `chris` etc. What is the optimal way to do this, without using the `like` clause. The suggestions will be only on the changes in the last part of the name.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `like` clause?

Comment: Consider switching to Postgres. It allows to do this using [text search dictionaries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html)

Comment: Can you add an new field? if so check my additional comment under my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want also similar names (by sound) something like `SOUNDEX()` could help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Otherwise `… LIKE 'chri%'` seems for me not a bad idea?

If you really want just the first characters without `LIKE` you can use `SUBSTRING()`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this one twice.  Of course if you're using SUBSTRING() to compare only the first characters, LIKE xyz% seems to do about the same thing.  But SOUNDEX()... that's a great suggestion and reminds me sort of the Lingua::EN::SimilarNames, Text::Soundex, and Lingua::EN::NameLookup CPAN modules for Perl (which wouldn't help because they require the dataset be imported first).

Comment: using SUBSTRING() will require a full table scan.  LIKE will be faster in this case.  SOUNDEX() is a good suggestion, but should be stored as a separate indexed field so searching is fast.

Answer (score 2):

You could use php's metaphone() function to generate the metaphone-code for each name and store them along with the names.

```
<?php
print "chris" . "\t" . metaphone("chris") . "\n";
print "christian" . "\t" . metaphone("christian") . "\n";
print "christine" . "\t" . metaphone("christine") . "\n";

# prints:
# chris      XRS
# christine  XRSTN
# christian  XRSXN
```

You can then use a levenshtein distance algorithm (either in php [http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php] or mysql [http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552]) to calculate the distance between the metacodes. In my test below a distance of 2 or less seemed to indicate the level of similarity that you are seeking.

```
<?php
$names = array(
        array('mike',metaphone('mike')),
        array('chris',metaphone('chris')),
        array('chrstian',metaphone('christian')),
        array('christine',metaphone('christine')),
        array('michelle',metaphone('chris')),
        array('mick',metaphone('mick')),
        array('john',metaphone('john')),
        array('joseph',metaphone('joseph'))
);

foreach ($names as $name) {
        _compare($name);
}

function _compare($n) {
        global $names;
        $name = $n[0];
        $meta = $n[1];

        foreach ($names as $cname) {
                printf("The distance between $name and {$cname[0]} is %d\n",                          
                  levenshtein($meta, $cname[1]));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Like` is generally a good solution, but another way to improve performance for this might be to create a partial column index and then submit queries at the same length as your prefix. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) regarding `col_name(length)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular experssion i think. I'm not goot at thme but there is a function called REGEXP that you can put in a WHERE clause. Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: `REGEXP` is handy for more complex queries, but will be much slower than `LIKE`.

Comment: I imagined that (i never used it) it was just to propose something different from "LIKE"!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOUNDS LIKE, I think it should be quite fast as well.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like

Comment: kalyoncu, this will probably do a good job, but will require a full table scan like SOUNDEX().

Comment: If you can create an additional field, you may avoid that. With each insert you insert soundex to that field and in search time it will be quite fast. Also you can build an index on that field. Hmm I guess this is a better answer than previous.

Comment: You can also convert a soundex string to a number as well it is in C#### format if I remember correctly. Where C is between 1-26 so 6 digit number at most.

Comment: but soundex isn't a very accurate algorithm to use. chris generates a code of C620, whereas christine and christian generate C623, so his above stated similarity would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Using LIKE where the left hand side is fixed won't require a table scan.  I'm assuming this is why you don't want to use LIKE : `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(?, "%")` is fast and won't require a table scan to find rows.  The CONCAT allows you to use prepared queries with % syntax.

You could also do something like:

`SELECT * from table WHERE name < 'christian' LIMIT 20`

and

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE name > 'christian' LIMIT 20`

to find neighbors in the sorted list.